# modal pop-up via ajax call and php function, passing function issues

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a button with on onclick event that passes the I am trying to have a pop up load through an ajax call via a php function with jquery. I am getting a response of Uncaught type error  $ is not a function, coming from the Ajax function. Clearly I am not passing this correctly but am unsure of the solution?

**ONCLICK CALL**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button seated-btn" onclick="toptions('+val.wait_id+')" data-id="'+val.wait_id+'">
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
    function toptions(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: {
        action: 'options'
                },      
        success: function (data) {
        $("#myModal").show()
                 ;}
            }); 
        }
```

**PHP FUNCTION**

```
function options(){ 
    ?>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<script>
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
} 
});
</script>
        <?php
}
```

Comment: You should use php statments inside your "function options(){  ?>", instead of putting javascript inside a php " function known as options() ". Alternatively,  modify your php function to a javascript function

Comment: Thanks the function is a php function and there will be other functions in there, I am just doing this one step at a time. What is the solution to it not passing through and the uncaught type error of$ is not a funciton?

Comment: can you load latest file of `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: @kumar, thanks. The answer below is it and it was spotted it is WP which doesnt support the $ variable

Comment: so what you want open modal with data in it to anchor click??

Comment: The onclick, passes to ajax which calls a php function. That is where the modal is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is not a function because you're using Wordpress and they restrict using of jquery variable `$` so instead of it use `jQuery("#myModal").show()`

Comment: Thanks so much. Wordpress strikes again:)